# jquery find element by src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this small gallery (the code is just example):

```
<div id="gallery_imgs">
    <img src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/112/0/9/nobody_believes_in_me_by_idjpanda-d7fkd7m.png" />
    <img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/112/5/6/feed_me_d__by_idjpanda-d7fgids.png" />
    <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/104/e/5/blar_auction_by_idjpanda-d7ehmoc.png" />
</div>
<p></p>
```

JS code:

```
var that = $("#gallery_imgs img:eq(1)");
$("p").html($("#gallery_imgs img").find("[src='"+that.attr("src")+"']").length);
```

This return 0. Any idea why? Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("p").html($("#gallery_imgs img").filter("[src='"+that.attr("src")+"']").length);
```

---

you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) this way

```
$("p").html($("#gallery_imgs").find("img [src='"+that.attr("src")+"']").length);
```

---

**Problem**

`$("#gallery_imgs img").find("[src='"+that.attr("src")+"']")` you are trying to find the element with `src` inside the `img` element not within in the `img` element

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("p").html($("#gallery_imgs img[src="+that.attr("src")+"]").length);
```